# We're all at sea!

Tags: riddle

My latest attempt at a riddle, feedback welcomed.

> In vain I return to you,
>   A few whacks and we got rid of the hare,
>   Can't we just pause for a minute?
>   What could we use to wine and dine? Mussels?
>   Sorry, we're all at sea aren't we?
>   Pretending to be naval.
>   Is this just a waste of my time?
>   Who knows!
>   I'm through with you!

**Edit**
The correct answer has been found by [rubio](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62120/45136), but there are a few missing answers to the clues. Remember to use a:

> homophone.

I've added some clues for each one below:

```
What could we use to wine and dine?
```

> Genuine question, [hexomino](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62109/45136)  was close.

```
Can't we just pause for a minute?
```

> Not a genuine question, think oil.

```
I'm through with you!
```

> Genuine statement, who is `you`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This riddle seems to be about

> **The body**, or at least, parts thereof.
>  [@hexomino](/users/18422/hexomino) is really who [cracked the puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62109), but missed the forest for the trees...?
>  The key is in the homophones!

`In vain I return to you,`

> **Blood**, which returns to the **heart** via the ***veins***.

`A few whacks and we got rid of the hare,`

> ***Hair***, which is (sometimes) gotten rid of by applying ***wax***.

`Can't we just pause for a minute?`

> <s>***Foramen***, an opening in e.g. a bone, often where blood vessels pass through.
>
>  (Also, arguably, **hands**, sometimes colloquially called *paws*.)</s>
> Added by OP: ***Pores***, as in pores on the face.

`What could we use to wine and dine? Mussels?`

> Added by OP: What could we use to *whine* and dine? **Mouth**.
>  ***Muscles***.  You do use them to eat and drink, and much much more.

`Sorry, we're all at sea aren't we?`

> **Eyes**, with which we *see*.

`Pretending to be naval.`

> ***Navel***, or belly-button.

`Is this just a waste of my time?`

> ***Waist***.

`Who knows!`

> ***Nose***.

`I'm through with you!`

> <s>Probably, "I'm through wi**th you**!" gives
>
>  ***Thew***, meaning "muscle or strength; nerve; brawn; sinew."</s>
>  Added by OP: I'm *threw* with you! An object is thrown by a **Hand**.

Comment: Very good, you got it. We're still missing 3 clues. Lines 3 and 9 are incorrect, and missing one on line 4.

Comment: @JackPettinger Line 3, I pronounce nothing like that... no wonder!  (I think my answer for line 3 is actually completely fine, in any case, even if not the one you intended)

Comment: Good point, I guess I didn't really think about how other people pronounce words.

Answer (score 7):

I think the answer might be that you are

> Homophones

Generally,

> Each line contains at least one homophone and a re-reading of each line with the replacement word hints at the answer.

In vain I return to you,

> In **vein**, I return to you, 
>  The first homophone is present in a sense without being directly stated.

A few whacks and we got rid of the hare,

> A few **wax** and we got rid of the **hair**, 
>  This line makes more sense with the homophone replacements.

Can't we just pause for a minute?

> Can't we just **paws** for a minute? 
>  Not sure about this line, open to suggestions

What could we use to wine and dine? Mussels?

> What could we use to **whine** and **dyne**? **Muscles**? 
>  Muscles may be used to whine or produce a dyne (unit of force).

Sorry, we're all at sea aren't we?

> Sorry, we're all at **see** aren't we? 
>  Homophones are distinguished only by sight not by sound.

Pretending to be naval.

> Pretending to be **navel.** 
>  This is a reference both to a homophone being mistaken for another word and the idea of navel-gazing (connected to the sight in the previous line).

Is this just a waste of my time?

> Is this just a **waist** of my time? 
>  The navel from the previous line is located near the waist.

Who knows!

> Who **nose!** 
>  Homophones invoke a confusion between sight and sound. This line is a reference to confusion of the senses.

I'm through with you!

> I'm **threw** with you! 
>  Homophones are designed to throw you off.

Additional notes

> The second half of the riddle suggests the *you* in the riddle might be eyesight and the entire riddle expresses the interplay between the senses and the confusion between them (especially sight and sound).

Comment: Excellent! Homophones are definitely a factor here, but all the clues are leading to something.

Comment: Maybe the word **paws** should actually be **praus**? That is the plural of **proa** which is a type of sailing boat in Malaysia. But I don't think this helps either, though it is just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Are you (partial)

> waves

In vain I return to you,

> 

A few whacks and we got rid of the hare,

> Pip Hare is a sailor, maybe waves knocking her off a boat?

Can't we just pause for a minute?

> when the sea is calm

What could we use to wine and dine? Mussels?

> something about mussels using the waves to get around..

Sorry, we're all at sea aren't we?

> waves are all at sea

Pretending to be naval.

> not sure / self explanatory

Is this just a waste of my time?

> 

Who knows!

> 

I'm through with you!

> 